# .htaccess for projects within a subfolder (xampp)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have several folders within /xampp/htdocs and I was trying to run a project I found on the net.

The structure goes like this:

```
/root
     /app
      --- /public
          ------
           index.php

          /morestuff
```

The app runs fine if the ROOT directory is pointed to public but I want the app to run without messing with Apache (and the other Xampp projects). The url is something like http://localhost/app/ and my goal is to browse that url and get to the index.

Is that possible? I've tried with many combinations of .htaccess but I don't know what else to do.

An example of what i've tried´(on /app):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/public$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you has to put .htaccess in specific project instead of putting in Apache.

If you modify Apache settings, it would be applicable to all projects. It's better to put that file in project folder.

Thanks!

Comment: The file is in the project, not in document root.